# Jhipster Release 1.6.0 - datepicker from create/edit modal is not working

Tags: datepicker, jhipster

I've upgraded jhipster from release 1.4.0 to 1.6.0 and I found that the datepicker isn't working anymore.

Maybe is not a big deal but I can't see why the datepicker is gone. The forms in both releases are identical.

Could anyone using jhipster answer this??

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Are you using Firefox? It does not support the HTML5 datepicker

Comment: You are right! From now on I will use Chrome all the way !! Thank you Julien :-)