# jhipster : which datepicker to use

Tags: datepicker, jhipster

I m trying to find a datepicker component which works with jhipster when used in modals.
I can't find a working one.
If someone uses such a datepicker, I wouldd be thankful to know which one it is.

Thanks.

Comment: This was adressed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134960/how-to-add-datepicker-at-jhipster-ui

Answer (score 0):

It comes with a built-in HTML5 datepicker, but it only works with Chrome apparently.
From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734609/jhipster-release-1-6-0-datepicker-from-create-edit-modal-is-not-working), the author of JHipster confirmed this.
I can confirm that it doesn't work in Firefox, and the one that shows up in Chrome does not look as nice as the Bootstrap-UI one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jHipster at the moment, and I use angular-daterangepicker AngularJS directive.

https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker

I have no problems, it works in modals and I hope it helps you.