# How to add DatePicker at JHipster UI

Tags: angularjs, compass-sass, angular-ui-bootstrap, jhipster

I want to modify one of JHipster entity page to use [DatePicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker). I Have include dependencies over Bower, add js library url to index page. I'm not sure how to include bootstrap css, should I use compass or something else? 
Or do you maybe know better library for UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added it to my project using WebJars:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I use class="date" on my date fields and use the following HTML/JS to initialize the field.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/webjars/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/css/datepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.date').datepicker({format: "mm/dd/yyyy", weekStart: "0"});
    });
</script>
```

---

To do it with Bower, I used the following steps:

In bower.json, add bootstrap-datepicker as a dependency. I added it just after bootstrap-sass.

```
"bootstrap-datepicker": "1.3.1"
```

Then run:

```
bower install
```

In src/main/webapp/index.html, add links to the CSS and JS files:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css">
    ...
</head>

<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

To prove it works, I added a "birthdate" field to register.html. Note the **data-provide** attribute triggers the popup calendar.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="birthdate">Birth Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="birthdate" data-provide="datepicker">
    </div>
```

Comment: This works but WebJars is not part of standard JHipster stack, that is one framework more. I thought that there is something more simple with existing stack there.

Comment: I added instructions for bower to my original answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: It works, thanks! ... how would i pass options? ... i need to change date format

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to this is to use AngularJS Bootstrap module which provides several other widgets apart from Datepicker.

```
bower install angular-bootstrap
```

Full Documentation [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) and [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap)