# Which is The best datepicker for jHipster?

Tags: datepicker, jhipster

I want to use datepicker in jHipster v4.8.2 project with Angular 4. I tried  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134960/how-to-add-datepicker-at-jhipster-ui) 
but it didn't work. I would be thankful if you have an idea.

Comment: show what you have tried?

Comment: [Matt Raible's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134960/how-to-add-datepicker-at-jhipster-ui?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7040) you can use [NgbTimepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/api) on "Instant" (= a java.time.Instant object), which jhipster.tech recommends to be most probably used instead of a "ZonedDateTime" (see [Field types](https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/)), or use the PrimeNG support - [here](https://youtu.be/JpbGrN21Aho?t=554) you can see a code example in detail.

You can also find my PrimeNG calendar-module implementation [here](https://github.com/Mesqualito/example_jhipster_ecommerceapp/commit/d5ca8fd57cbc317eb84c6936c75ea6f0c9674a57) - trying to get the example app from [Full Stack Development with JHipster](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/full-stack-development-jhipster) done.